# Rescaling and reciprocal a set with empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume $A\subset \Bbb R$ with empty interior, that is, there is no $a, b\in \Bbb R$ with $a<b$ such that $$(a,b)\subset A$$ let $r\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ then $r A$ still has an empty interior. For contradiction, assume there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\subset r A$ but this implies $$\frac{1}{r} (a,b)\subset A$$ notice that $\frac{1}{r} (a,b)$ is an open set  which is a contradiction since $A$ has an empty interior.

Also, assume $0\notin A$, the set $B:=\{\frac{1}{a}\colon a\in A\}$ has an empty interior. The argument is as above.

Now, assume what I said above it is correct. if $A=\{a_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ has an empty interior how about  $$\{r_\xi a_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}?$$  Does it still have an empty interior? where $r_\xi$ is a real number for every $\xi<\mathfrak c$

Could you please check my work and tell if it is correct or not? Or there is another way to show it.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}=\{x_\xi:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}$, and without loss of generality assume that $0\notin A$. For $\xi<\mathfrak{c}$ let $r_\xi=\frac{x_\xi}{a_\xi}$; then

$$\{r_\xi a_\xi:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}=\{x_\xi:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\,.$$

Comment: Brain. M Scott. Thank you . but what I did was fine right

Comment: @00GB: You’re welcome. The part about rescaling or taking reciprocals is correct: both operations preserve the property of having empty interior.

Comment: Brain M.Scott, assume $D\subset \Bbb R$ with $|D|=\mathfrak c$ and has an empty interior and a function $f$ is neither injective nor surjective on $D$. Also, $f$ is not constant function  $B:=\{x^{-1}f(x)\colon x\in D\}$. Does $B$ have empty interior ?

Comment: @00GB: Not necessarily.  You could always construct such a function $f$ so that $B=[0,1]$, for instance.

Comment: Brian M. Scott. Thank you. How if $D$ meager set ? Is it $B$ meager ?

Comment: @00GB: I’ve not checked the details carefully, but I’m pretty sure that as long as $|D|=\mathfrak{c}$, you can construct $f$ so that $B$ is an interval.

Comment: @Brain M. Scott. Thank you for your explanation. It seems without construction $f$ carefully there is no control. Is that right ?

Comment: @00GB: You’re welcome.  Yes, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Brain M, Scott, I think , I know why I am confused . I have seen an example with $D$ meager set and $B:=\{x-f(x)\colon x\in D\}$ . If I am not wrong $B$ is meager set.

Comment: @00GB: That also is going to depend on $f$: one could construct $f$ to make $B$ any set of the same cardinality as $D$.

Comment: Brain. M. Scott.  you are right. Ii just checked the example it assumed $f$ to be constant on $D$. So, it is just shifting . which of course meager